# SSRS Count grouped rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report where i'm trying to SUM row counts (or SUM count ID) per group.  I'm not sure how to do this in SSRS.  The report looks like below

[image]

and I'm trying to create the highlighted area in red.  How can this be done?  The problem is the rows above the red area are already in a group...

I've tried Count("Group1"), =Count(ContainerID) but when i do count on the ID field it's giving me a count on ALL the records in the data set and not what's above... Any ideas? I've inherited this report and have been asked to make changes to it...

Comment: What is the red area grouped by? If it is already grouped by something else, could you do a child group on CustomerId? What value do you get back now? 10 for all destinations? Also, please include your dataset and sample data if possible.

Comment: The red area is what i'm trying to create based on the data above which is already grouped... Like I said I tried to do a count of ContainerID, but I was getting a much higher count than what is displayed above as i'm guessing it was doing a count on the whole dataset not just the group that is displayed... i'm afraid I can't provide any more data etc. as the code isn't SQL it's being retrieved by code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using =CountDistinct(ContainerID.Value) in No of Containers field.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't restricted to doing everything in the one table.

Create a second table under the one you show here based on the same dataset, group by destination, show the count, and hide the detail row.

Comment: Hi could you please provide a step by step?  I've created many reports but I don't have much experience with this fiddly grouping stuff...